# How to convert a struct to hdf5 format and save it with octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a struct value in my code. I need to convert to h5 format. I was trying to use the octave save method in this way:

```
s = save ("-hdf5","train.h5","-struct","startloc")
```

where, train.h5 is the file where I want to save it and startloc is the variable of type struct containing two key values.

```
startloc = struct('dat',[1,1,1,totalct+1], 'lab', [1,1,1,totalct+1]);
```

When i try to run it, I get the error,

> error: value on right hand side of assignment is undefined

The h5 files is being created but the it cant find the startloc as it is considering it as string might be. But the syntax of the save command does not allow me to pass without quotes for arguments. I searched a lot in octave doc but no way it works.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right.

This appears to be an Octave bug: the `save()` function is not returning anything.

So just don't capture its output.

```
totalct = 2;
startloc = struct('dat',[1,1,1,totalct+1], 'lab', [1,1,1,totalct+1]);
save ("-hdf5", "train.h5", "-struct", "startloc")
```

If you care about this behavior, report it as a bug to [the GNU Octave bug tracker on Savannah](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=octave).